# android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception

I get this error:

```
06-06 10:45:19.685: E/AndroidRuntime(554): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.Android.myApp/com.Android.myApp.Facebook.Example}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

But i have declared it in my manifest file. what might be the other reasons for such exception?

My manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.Android.myApp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" >

        <activity
            android:name=".SignUpActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SignInActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".selectCityActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".FeedListViewActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SearchActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".IWantActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".DateActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ShareActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ShareProductActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SharePriceActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ShareStoreActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ProfileActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ShowMapActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ParticularEntryActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MyLocationActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MapMarkerActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".BarcodeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".BarcodeResult"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".FeedbackActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Example"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Maybe the library class is not referred properly

Comment: how to make sure it is referred properly??...its there in the properties --> Library.

Comment: show your Manifest file.

Comment: @Lalit Poptani...this is what i included in my manifest.xml...<activity
            android:name=".Example"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

Comment: @Archie.bpgc complete Manifest file with do to understand not a single line.

Comment: From your exception which one is your class - `Facebook` or `Example` Because, you declared in package in manifest as `com.android.myapp` but for facebook activity you declared `com.android.myapp.Facebook.Example`

Comment: Example is my activity in com.Android.myApp.Facebook package

Comment: If example is your activity means, you should declared your activity as `com.android.myapp.Facebook.Example` Because, its from different package or your Activity name as `Facebook.Example`. Am i right?

Comment: yeah...i never used this way...it worked

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You declared package name in the manifest as `com.Android.myApp` and Activity Name `.Example`.So android will search it from `com.Android.myApp.Example`.
But your activity is residing in  "`com.Android.myApp/com.Android.myApp.Facebook.Example`".So give the activity name as `.Facebook.Example` or full path as given below 
In the manifest

```
<activity
                android:name="com.Android.myApp.Facebook.Example">

</activity>
```

Comment: Tag <activity> attribute name has invalid character '/'.

Comment: The key point is to **remember to include the dot "." at the front**, when declaring the Activity without the full package name. It's easy to forget this dot, and Android Studio will sometimes suggest (auto-complete) without the dot! When the dot is missing, you will get this error unexpectedly.

Answer (score 6):

you can also use

```
<activity
        android:name=".Facebook.Example"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Answer (score 6):

I got a variation to this problem. I was launching an activity called *"Settings"* and getting the same error and making all the suggested changes to the manifest were not fixing the problem.

Thing is, in the calling activity, I was also using / importing android.provider.Settings, so from what I can see when trying to launch the activity it was getting confused between the two. Thus I changed this in the code rather than the manifest to include the full path:

```
Intent launchScr = new Intent(this, com.foo.bar.Settings.class);
```

And it worked. Of course, the other, and better, way to solve this particular issue would be to use better names for my activities.

HTH anyone with this variant of the problem.

Comment: In my case i had written the spelling of Activity wrong

Comment: I had a PreferencesActivity and there seems to be an Android class of that name which had an include statement.  Similar cause.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes,It's due to existence of the same class name (second parameter of the Intent) in different packages.

I found also that this occurs when you call startService instead of calling startActivity and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

From your exception which one is your class - `Facebook` or `Example` Because, you declared in package in manifest as `com.Android.myApp` But, for `facebook` activity you declared `com.android.myApp.Facebook.Example` And,

If example is your activity means, you should declared your activity as `com.Android.myApp.Facebook.Example` Because, its from different package or your Activity name as `Facebook.Example` So better you can declare your Activity like below -

```
<activity
        android:name="com.Android.myApp.Facebook.Example"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Answer (score 2):

This can happen on large projects when the cached manifest gets out of sync.  I was able to fix it in the Android Studio terminal with `./gradlew clean` and then in the Android Studio menu bar selecting **File** > **Invalidate Caches / Restart** for good measure

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure your Activity is decorated with this attribute:

```
[Activity(Label = "Your App Name", MainLauncher=true)]
```

Note: Only Set MainLauncher if needed.

Answer (score 0):

This works if you have an Activity object (which you need to launch):

```
 intent.setClassName(CallingActivity.this, activityToLaunch.getComponentName().getClassName());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this code if you wish to change your class dynamically from string:
`Intent intent = new Intent().setClassName(this.getPackageName(), "com.some.other.name");`
or you can put result from array or any other instead of "com.some.other.name". Cheers!