# Calling an activity from class which is extended to other class,which is extended from fragment

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-manifest

I am developing an android app and I am extending my class 1 from one of my other class 2 and that other class 2 is extended from fragment .When I try to call other class from class 1 using intent I get error .Either I have also registered the new class in Manifest file.
Class 1 whose name is abstract fragment is this:

```
public abstract class AbstractFragment extends Fragment implements IFragment {

    /**
     * Fragment title
     */
    private String mTitle;

    /**
     * Enable or not the fragment
     */
    protected boolean mEnable;

    /**
     * Setter for the field mTitle
     * 
     * @param mTitle
     *            the mTitle to set
     */
    public void setTitle(final String mTitle) {
        this.mTitle = mTitle;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for the field mEnable
     * 
     * @param mEnable
     *            the mEnable to set
     */
    public void setEnable(final boolean mEnable) {
        this.mEnable = mEnable;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnable() {
        return mEnable;
    }

}
```

Class 2 whose name is CardDetailFragment :

```
public class CardDetailFragment extends AbstractFragment {

    /**
     * Card to display
     */
    private EmvCard mCard;

    /**
     * Empty view
     */
    private LinearLayout mEmptyView;

    /**
     * Card view
     */
    private ScrollView mScrollView;

    /**
     * Card number
     */
    private TextView mCardNumber;

    /**
     * Card validity
     */
    private TextView mCardValidity;

    /**
     * Image view
     */
    private ImageView mImageView;

    /**
     * Extended layout
     */
    private TableLayout mExtendedLayout;

    /**
     * Method used to create a new instance of the fragment
     * 
     * @param pCard
     *            EmvCard
     * @param pTitle
     *            fragment title
     * @return fragment
     */
    Button pay;
    public static IFragment newInstance(final EmvCard pCard, final String pTitle) {
        CardDetailFragment ret = new CardDetailFragment();
        ret.setEnable(true);
        ret.setTitle(pTitle);
        ret.setCard(pCard);
        return ret;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_detail, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(final View view, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Get views
        mEmptyView = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.emptyView);
        mScrollView = (ScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_detail);
        mCardNumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardNumber);
        mCardValidity = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardValidity);
        mImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.type);
        mExtendedLayout = (TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.extended_content);
        // Set OCR-A typeface
        ViewUtils.setTypeFace(EmvApplication.sTypeface, mCardNumber, mCardValidity);
        pay=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        pay.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        pay.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        // Update content
        updateContent();
        pay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(),CaptureSignature.class);

                startActivity(in);


            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Method used to update card detail content
     */
    private void updateContent() {
        if (getActivity() != null) {
            if (mCard != null) {
                mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mScrollView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                // Update content
                mCardNumber.setText(CardUtils.formatCardNumber(mCard.getCardNumber(), mCard.getType()));
                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yy", Locale.getDefault());
                mCardValidity.setText(format.format(mCard.getExpireDate()));
                mImageView.setImageResource(CardUtils.getResourceIdCardType(mCard.getType()));

                // Extended card data

                // Remove all existing view
                mExtendedLayout.removeAllViews();

                // Card holder name
                if (mCard.getHolderName() != null && mCard.getHolderName().length() > 1) {
                    createRaw(getString(R.string.extended_card_holder_name), mCard.getHolderName());
                }

                // card AID
                if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(mCard.getAid())) {
                    createRaw(getString(R.string.extended_title_AID), CardUtils.formatAid(mCard.getAid()));
                }

                // Card Application label
                if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(mCard.getApplicationLabel())) {
                    createRaw(getString(R.string.extended_title_application_label), mCard.getApplicationLabel());
                }

                // Card type
                if (mCard.getType() != null) {
                    createRaw(getString(R.string.extended_title_card_type), mCard.getType().getName());
                }

                // Pin try left
                createRaw(getString(R.string.extended_title_pin_try), mCard.getLeftPinTry() + " "
                        + getString(R.string.extended_title_times));

                // Atr desc
                if (mCard.getAtrDescription() != null && !mCard.getAtrDescription().isEmpty()) {
                    createRaw(getString(R.string.extended_title_possible_bank), StringUtils.join(mCard.getAtrDescription(), "\n"));
                }

            } else {
                mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mScrollView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method used to create a row in the section "Extended card detail"
     * 
     * @param pKeyName
     *            key title
     * @param pValue
     *            key value
     */
    private void createRaw(final String pKeyName, final String pValue) {
        View v = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.tablelayout_raw, null);
        TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.extended_raw_title);
        title.setText(pKeyName);
        TextView content = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.extended_raw_content);
        content.setText(pValue);
        mExtendedLayout.addView(v);
    }

    public void update(final EmvCard pCard) {
        mCard = pCard;
        updateContent();
    }

    /**
     * Setter for the field mCard
     * 
     * @param mCard
     *            the mCard to set
     */
    public void setCard(final EmvCard mCard) {
        this.mCard = mCard;
    }

}
```

The class I am trying to call is named CaptureSignature.
Error Log is:

```
08-24 09:10:50.761: E/AndroidRuntime(15732): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-24 09:10:50.761: E/AndroidRuntime(15732): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.github.devnied.emvnfccard/com.github.devnied.emvnfccard.fragment.viewPager.impl.CaptureSignature}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
08-24 09:10:50.761: E/AndroidRuntime(15732):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1635)
08-24 09:10:50.761: E/AndroidRuntime(15732):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1434)
08-24 09:10:50.761: E/AndroidRuntime(15732):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3430)
08-24 09:10:50.761: E/AndroidRuntime(15732):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3391)
08-24 09:10:50.761: E/AndroidRuntime(15732):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:840)
08-24 09:10:50.761: E/AndroidRuntime(15732):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3626)
08-24 09:10:50.761: E/AndroidRuntime(15732):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3594)
08-24 09:10:50.761: E/AndroidRuntime(15732):    at com.github.devnied.emvnfccard.fragment.viewPager.impl.CardDetailFragment$1.onClick(CardDetailFragment.java:120)
08-24 09:10:50.761: E/AndroidRuntime(15732):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4354)
08-24 09:10:50.761: E/AndroidRuntime(15732):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17961)
08-24 09:10:50.761: E/AndroidRuntime(15732):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-24 09:10:50.761: E/AndroidRuntime(15732):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-24 09:10:50.761: E/AndroidRuntime(15732):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-24 09:10:50.761: E/AndroidRuntime(15732):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
08-24 09:10:50.761: E/AndroidRuntime(15732):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-24 09:10:50.761: E/AndroidRuntime(15732):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-24 09:10:50.761: E/AndroidRuntime(15732):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
08-24 09:10:50.761: E/AndroidRuntime(15732):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
08-24 09:10:50.761: E/AndroidRuntime(15732):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Manifest file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.github.devnied.emvnfccard"
    android:versionCode="12"
    android:versionName="2.0.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:name="com.github.devnied.emvnfccard.EmvApplication"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.first"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
                android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_list" />
        </activity>
        <activity   android:name=".activity.HomeActivity"></activity>
         <activity  android:name=".activity.currencies"></activity>
          <activity  android:name=".activity.CaptureSignature"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: show your manifest file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
<activity  android:name=".activity.CaptureSignature"></activity>
```

to this

```
<activity  android:name=".fragment.viewPager.impl.CaptureSignature"></activity>
```

or give full path to your activity

```
<activity  android:name="com.github.devnied.emvnfccard.fragment.viewPager.impl.CaptureSignature"></activity>
```

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908534/android-content-activitynotfoundexception-unable-to-find-explicit-activity-clas

Comment: why the other activities does not need full path?

Comment: remember that com.github.devnied.emvnfccard is equivalent to com.github.devnied.emvnfccard.fragment.viewPager.impl.CaptureSignature