# Unfortunately, my application has stopped

Tags: android

> 03-31 21:26:47.921 21954-21954/com.example.user.letseat E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                             Process: com.example.user.letseat, PID: 21954
>                                                                             android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.user.letseat/com.example.user.letseat.SignUp}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
>                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1788)
>                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1512)
>                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3873)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:67)
>                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3824)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:720)
>                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4154)
>                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4122)
>                                                                                 at com.example.user.letseat.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:33)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4848)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20262)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)

Comment: check your manifest file and add your  `activity` inside the manifest

Comment: `<activity android:name=".SignUp"/>`  add this line inside your manifest application tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908534/android-content-activitynotfoundexception-unable-to-find-explicit-activity-clas)

Comment: @akhilesh0707 thank you very much. it help me. im touched. sorry for my broken english hehe

Comment: @ADM how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `SignUp` entry inside `AndroidManifest.xml` file that why you getting

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class
>   {com.example.user.letseat/com.example.user.letseat.SignUp}; have you
>   declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

add this line inside your `AndroidManifest.xml` application tag

```
<activity android:name=".SignUp"/>
```

Comment: ohh i get it. it help me. seriously thank for helping. should i add all the activity in the menifest ?

Comment: @hajarsyahindah Yes you need to add all activities in manifest.

Answer (score 0):

**have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?**

Please declare your activity in your manifest file, as follows:

```
<activity
     android:name="com.example.package.YourActivityName"
     android:label="app_name" />
```

Comment: yes, i have declare it. but still the same. and for app_name, it is my application name or it is default app_name? do you get me ? and other thing, it must in the activity right ? oh i think i must show you the coding.

Comment: You can actually remove the label part, and no. The app_name is a place holder for you to put your app name