# Unable to find explicit activity class in barcode_scanner flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, hybrid-mobile-app, barcode-scanner

```html
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}
def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
  throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.pwlp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

```html
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.pwlp">

    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="Partner Perks"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
                 until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
                 there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
                 defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
                android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.apptreesoftware.barcodescan.BarcodeScannerActivity"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

barcode_scanner in flutter:-
I have integrated barcode scanner in flutter for my hybrid app.
By following this git link.
Link:- https://github.com/apptreesoftware/flutter_barcode_reader

Everything goes good.I am stuck by android app crash,

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:barcode_scan/barcode_scan.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class Scanner extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ScannerState createState() => _ScannerState();
}

class _ScannerState extends State<Scanner> {

  String result = "Hey there !";

  Future _scanQR() async {
    try {
      String qrResult = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
      setState(() {
        result = qrResult;
      });
    } on PlatformException catch (ex) {
      if (ex.code == BarcodeScanner.CameraAccessDenied) {
        setState(() {
          result = "Camera permission was denied";
          print(result);
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          result = "Unknown Error $ex";
          print(result);
        });
      }
    } on FormatException {
      setState(() {
        result = "You pressed the back button before scanning anything";
        print(result);
      });
    } catch (ex) {
      setState(() {
        result = "Unknown Error $ex";
        print(result);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          result,
          style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
        label: Text("Scan Now"),
        onPressed: _scanQR,
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
    );
  }
}
```

I am getting an error:-

android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.pwlp/com.apptreesoftware.barcodescan.BarcodeScannerActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Any Suggestion or I have do something else to resolve.

Please Help.
Thanks

Comment: Please share your AndroidManifest.xml, your project-level build.gradle and your app-level build.gradle

Comment: I have added the AndroidManifest codes in my question, please check and help me.

Comment: you forgot to share the gradle files i mentioned. AndroidManifest looks good.

Comment: buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()}
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
       classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }}
rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Comment: ok, this is your project-level build.gradle and now post your app-level build.gradle, please

Comment: Added in Question above, Please check.

Comment: i think it is a package problem. Same or similar discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10908567/2281606

Comment: Thanks a lot @A.D. But I have followed the .git link. and youtube tuts. They all done same. I don't know why I am getting this error in Android, As iOS is working like charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, I deleted the flutter_app/android/.gradle folder and it's works for me.

Comment: Thanks, I got the solution by adding to my debug AndroidManifest file.

<activity android:name="com.apptreesoftware.barcodescan.BarcodeScannerActivity"/>

Comment: The deleting did help!