# Kotlin unable to find explicit Activity class

Tags: android, kotlin, button, android-recyclerview

I have already looking posts which talk about this error but nothing seems me false. I need your help because in a recycler view, I put this code to start a new activity when we click on an item. I have not finish but it doesn't work because of a :

```
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {fr.amseu.myapp/fr.amseu.myapp.Activity.LowerLegsActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2069)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1717)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5250)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5208)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5579)
        at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity(ContextCompat.java:251)
        at fr.amseu.mystretching.adapter.MuscleAdapter$onBindViewHolder$1.onClick(MuscleAdapter.kt:58)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7870)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7839)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:886)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29363)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7948)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```

And the app crash when we click on the correspondant button. Here is my setup for the button, and it works fine before I added this line :

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int)     {
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{
            val onGroupClickListener = object  : OnGroupClickListener{}
            onGroupClickListener.onGroupItemClicked(position)

            if (position == 0) {
                CommentairePopup(this).show()
            } else if (position == 1) {
                
                //line which cause the problem
                val intent = Intent(context, LowerLegsActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(context, intent, null)
            } else if (position == 2) {
            } else if (position == 3) {
            } else if (position == 4) {
            } else if (position == 5) {
            } else if (position == 6) {
            }
        }
}
```

that is my manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="fr.amseu.mystretching">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyStretching">
        <activity android:name=".activity.ChronometerActivity"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".lowerLegsActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_itam_exercices"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyStretching.Fullscreen"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".exercices"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_exercices"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyStretching.Fullscreen" />
        <activity
            android:name=".item_exercices"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_itam_exercices"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyStretching.Fullscreen" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

My activity is fine... If you have a clue of what can I review... If you need more informations, I am open !
Thanks for taking your time for this !

Comment: "...and my manifest too..." -- not according to the error message. Could you edit your question and post your manifest?

Comment: Can you please share your manifest entry as well?

Comment: it is done @CommonsWare

Comment: and @NavjotSinghBedi

Comment: Your `Intent` is for `fr.amseu.myapp.Activity.LowerLegsActivity`, in an application ID of `fr.amseu.myapp`. Your manifest entry appears to be for `fr.amseu.mystretching.LowerLegsActivity`. These do not match, and they need to. I recommend updating the `package` attribute in your manifest to match your application ID, and update the `android:name` of the `<activity>` to match where the activity class resides.

Comment: @CommonsWare that was me who edit with a bad manifest, which correspond not with my app, my bad. But everything is fine, I just add Activity before `lowerLegsActivity` and it works !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What's Happening?**

The activity `lowerLegsActivity` name seems incorrect in the manifest. Your application package name as per manifest is `fr.amseu.mystretching`, but the package in which your class `LowerLegsActivity` lies is different as per error logs i.e. `fr.amseu.myapp.Activity`

**Solution 1 (Quick Fix)**

**Replace this**

```
android:name=".lowerLegsActivity"
```

**With**

```
android:name="fr.amseu.myapp.Activity.LowerLegsActivity"
```

**Solution 2 (Recommended)**

Move class `LowerLegsActivity` to package `fr.amseu.mystretching.Activity` and perform the following replacement in the manifest

**Replace this**

```
android:name=".lowerLegsActivity"
```

**With**

```
android:name=".Activity.LowerLegsActivity"
```

Similar Issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10908567/1890849

Comment: Yes I fixed the problem with the second solution, thank you nevertheless @NavjotSinghBedi !

Comment: @AmaurySeuriot: great, kindly accept this answer if it solved your problem.