# Android Studio Kotlin: Button continually causes crashes when clicked

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

So I am brand new to coding and I'm making an app in `Android Studio` in `Kotlin` and on the homepage of my app I have a button that is supposed to take me to another `activity` and every time I click on it, the app crashes. I want to know how to fix this, and if it is a code error or a memory error. Thanks in advance!

Here's the code:

```
package com.smvcalculator

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val MaleLP = findViewById<Button>(R.id.malebtn)
        MaleLP.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, MaleLP::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

    }
}
```

Logcat Error:

```
2021-07-14 14:51:57.879 9421-9421/com.smvcalculator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.smvcalculator, PID: 9421
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.smvcalculator/com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2065)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1727)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5320)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:574)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5278)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:560)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5664)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5617)
        at com.smvcalculator.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda-0(MainActivity.kt:15)
        at com.smvcalculator.MainActivity.lambda$pO9IRxlIimBerH3k2cIfwv6P3Wg(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.smvcalculator.-$$Lambda$MainActivity$pO9IRxlIimBerH3k2cIfwv6P3Wg.onClick(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
2021-07-14 14:51:58.073 9421-9421/com.smvcalculator I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 9421 SIG: 9
```

Comment: What's the error in logcat when app is crashing?

Comment: What is the name of the activity?

Comment: Activity name: activity_name.xml

Comment: and I updated the bio and showed the log

Comment: Does this answer your question? [android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908534/android-content-activitynotfoundexception-unable-to-find-explicit-activity-clas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the error. Your `Button` has the same name like the `Activity` that will be used for `intent`. Change it to this:

```
package com.smvcalculator

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val maleLP_button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.malebtn) //new button name
        maleLP_button.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, MaleLP::class.java) //different to class name
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

Now it should work :)

Comment: Did the first suggestion, haven't ran the code yet but what is the benefit of doing the second thing???   Where you said                                                                                                                                        "And I bet you forget to define the new Activity into your AndroidManifest.xml. So add this piece of code above your other <activity:

<activity android:name="com.smvcalculator.MaleLP"/>"

Comment: You need to define that another activity is there. Without that it can not be initialized. Did you try to add it?

Comment: Didn't work, this is what I got. .......\SMVCalculator\app\src\main\java\com\smvcalculator\MainActivity.kt: (14, 33): Unresolved reference: context

Comment: and yeah I did, I made the variable and referenced the activity, maybe I didn't do it right.class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val MaleLP = findViewById<Button>(R.id.malebtn)
        MaleLP.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(context, MaleLP::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

    }
}You can check this code above as well in the description

Comment: So you defined both classes in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: I found the error. I updated my answer. Take a look. I rebuild your app and it worked for me.

Comment: Thank you so much! So it was because of conflicting names with the same names?

Comment: Exactly! So it gave a compilation error. Tick the question correct (hook) to help others facing the same error. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the issue here is, it says that `have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?` So you need to add this activity's name in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, i.e. `MaleLP.java` like this:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MaleLP"
       />
```

Comment: great to hear that :)